# what is difference between variant vs component in typography for library React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React Material UI  component.
Typography component has 2 props, variant and component.What is the difference between these props.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some predefine styles can be used with **variant** but final HTML element to be rendered can be set with component. e.g. you can use `variant="body1"` with `component="h2"` or `variant="body2"` with `component="h2"` that has smaller font-size.

Answer (score 2):

1. variant: use styles of normal html tag
2. component: make final result tag as this tag
3. For example, variant="h5" component="h1"

   - applied style: h5 tag
   - final result tag: h1 tag
     (you can check: Chrome browser > deleveloment tool > Elements tab)

Answer (score 1):

variant => you use styles of normal html tag.

component => you use a React element for root node.

Comment: about "you use styles of normal html tag": well, *img* for example is a "normal html tag", what do you mean by "using" its styles?